# Fixed 5V regulator circuit LM1084

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am building a circuit using a fixed 5V LM1084.

All the circuit diagrams in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1084.pdf) seem to be for the adjustable configurations. To used the 5V fixed should I connect Adj/GND pin directly to ground?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you connect the ADJ/GND pin to Ground aka GND for the fixed-output versions.

Eg. Figure 12:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I assume I still need the bypass/decoupling capacitors?

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz Of course! They're to prevent ripples. If you don't really need a very accurate power supply, you could skip them but if you want the regulator to meet its specifications, you better insert them.

Comment: Thank you, as a software guy, reading the datasheets is easy but fully grasping them will take a little more work

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz Yes, and like most LDOs you **need** them and they have to be of the correct type to ensure stability, otherwise the regulator can turn into an oscillator. You show tantalums, which are no problem (in that respect) since they have an acceptable range of ESR but if you get the urge to replace the output capacitor with a ceramic type (perhaps because you experience an unfortunate but typical 'ignition' event with a tantalums at high available current) you may have to add resistance in series (read the data sheet carefully- I scanned it and saw insufficient information). Old chip.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Would you recommend using a switching type regulator instead of an LDO? I'm looking for 5V, 5A.

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz Absolutely, especially for a digital circuit where a bit of noise doesn't hurt. At 5A your LTxxx would be dissipating 20 watts, which is a very large amount of heat to get rid of and keep the chip cool enough- big heat sink and/or fan. Also very wasteful.

Comment: Great thanks, I will look into a switching regulator than can provide that amount of power. Are there any commonly used ranges that would be a good first point of call?

Comment: Try looking at modules- cost a bit more, maybe, but easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

> To used the 5V fixed should I connect Adj/GND pin directly to ground?

Correct - confirmed from section 5 of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1084.pdf):

[image: L1084 pinout]

where it says that pin 1 is: "Adjust pin for the adjustable output voltage version. **Ground pin for the fixed output voltage versions**."

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  As listed on page 3:

> Adjust pin for the adjustable output voltage version. ***Ground pin for the fixed output voltage versions.***

Comment: Thanks, I understood that the Adj was GND for the fixed version but was unsure if any extra circuitry was required around this.

Comment: @bradman175 it's it's a TO-220 regulator. Not a M8 threaded screw.

Comment: @Passerby lol... *mate.